Problems using logfmt time in promtail-loki-grafana
I have problems with the trace registration date in loki, I want to use the log date (logfmt) and when viewing it in grafana I see the upload date.
docker.compose
version: "3"

networks:
  tracing:

services:
  grafana:
    container_name: grafana-2
    image: grafana/grafana:10.4.1
    volumes:
      - './run/resources/datasource.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yaml'
      - './dockerVolumes/grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana'
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - TZ=UTC
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - tracing

  loki:
    container_name: loki
    image: grafana/loki:2.9.6
    volumes:
      - './dockerVolumes/loki_data:/loki'
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    networks:
      - tracing

  promtail:
    container_name: promtail
    image: grafana/promtail:2.9.6
    volumes:
      - './run/resources/promtail-config.yml:/etc/promtail/config.yml'
      - './run/logs:/var/log'
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    networks:
      - tracing


config promtail
positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: od
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost
        labels:
          job: od_logs
          __path__: /var/log/od/*.log
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['__path__']
        regex: '/var/log/od/(.*)\.log'
        action: replace
        target_label: logfilename
        replacement: '${1}'
    pipeline_stages:
      - logfmt:
          mapping:
            timestamp: time
      - timestamp:
          source: time
          format: RFC3339

config loki
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

ingester:
  max_transfer_retries: 0
  rate_limit_bytes: 8388608
  chunk_idle_period: 1h
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  lifecycler:
    address: localhost
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
  client:
    backoff_config:
      max_period: 5s


schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-05-15
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

storage_config:
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /loki/index
    cache_location: /loki/index_cache
    cache_ttl: 24h
    shared_store: filesystem
  filesystem:
    directory: /loki/chunks
    index_queries_cache_config:
      cache:
        max_size: 50000
        item_size_bytes: 5000
        max_age: 1h
    index_queries_cache:
      enabled: true

compactor:
  working_directory: /loki/compactor
  shared_store: filesystem

limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: false
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 999999h 
  unordered_writes: true

chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0s


example log
time=2024-04-04T18:15:55.434 level=trace thread=3214 origin=libOD msg="9000"
time=2012-11-01T22:08:41+00:00 level=trace thread=3214 origin=libOD msg="9000"
time=2024-04-04T18:15:55.434 level=trace thread=3214 origin=libOD msg="event processed successfully"

Problem time grafana

https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/stages/logfmt/
https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/installation/
https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/troubleshooting/

The timestamp stage looks for a field in the extracted map. However, Only the field timestamp can be found in the extracted mapping. So, You can try this way.
    pipeline_stages:
      - logfmt:
          mapping:
            time:
      - timestamp:
          source: time
          format: RFC3339


I have already tried that, by putting debug mode in promtail you can see how time sends it well in the log. It seems that the problem is in loki or grafana.

DEBUG PROMTAIL
2024-04-09 10:54:25 level=debug ts=2024-04-09T08:54:25.469758957Z caller=logfmt.go:147 component=file_pipeline component=stage type=logfmt msg="extracted data debug in logfmt stage" extracteddata="map[filename:/var/log/od/ejemplo de log us-od - 09_PRUEBAS.log job:od_logs logfilename:* time:2024-04-05T10:05:27.274Z]"
LOG
time="2024-04-05T10:05:27.274Z" level=info thread=4888

Does Promtail have any error logs?

I was missing the loki configuration, which was currently not applying the yml

'./run/resources/loki-config.yml:/etc/loki/config.yml'

